# SQLException: invalid schema name - saiku analytics pentaho using db2

Tags: db2, pentaho, cube, sqlexception, saiku

I am using pentaho 5.2 for saiku analytics. I created a cube, published using schema workbench. The cube appears in the saiku list of cubes. But when I set the columns and rows to generate the report, I get an error saying

"SQLException: invalid schema name: PBBA in statement [select "tablename"."columnname" as "c0" from "schemaname"."tablename"]"

Just to make sure if I am not missing any steps, this is what I did. I am using db2. I created a cube (sure no errors) and published it. Installed saiku from marketplace in pentaho 5.2. The cube appeared in the list of cubes.

I am not very sure about the problem, but i find this issue as it says the table name as in select "tablename"."columnname" which I guess is invalid in db2. That could be an issue. I need help with this, as I am very new to pentaho.